# How to upload recorded sound in P5.sound.js

Tags: javascript, html, audio, microphone

I have created a program which records sound from web browser using P5.sound.js.

```
 var mic, recorder, soundFile;  
        function setup(){
            mic = new p5.AudioIn(); 
            mic.start(); 
            recorder = new p5.SoundRecorder(); 
            recorder.setInput(mic); 
            soundFile = new p5.SoundFile(); 
        } 
        $("[name=btnRecord]").on("click",function(){ 
            recorder.record(soundFile);
            $("[name=btnRecord]").html("Recording...");
        }); 
        $("[name=btnStop]").on("click",function(){
            recorder.stop(); 
            $("[name=btnRecord]").html("Record"); 
        }); 
        $("[name=btnPlay]").on("click",function(){   
            soundFile.play();  
        }); 
        $("[name=btnDownload]").on("click",function(){ 
            saveSound(soundFile, 'mySound.wav'); 
        });
        $("[name=btnUpload]").on("click",function(){ 
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url:"upload.php",
                 data: {sound: soundFile},
                success: function(response){

                },
                dataType: "json"
              });  
        });
```

See the btnUpload handler. I want to upload the recorded sound to server. What code should I write? sound: soundFile does not work.